# Laravel: orderby count on pivot while filtering parent with keyword

Tags: php, laravel, count, pivot-table, laravel-8

Good morning everybody,

I have two tables, `users`, `questions` and one pivot table `users_questions`. A question belongs to many users. A user has many questions.

```
users
-----
id | name

questions
---------
id | description

users_questions
---------------
user_id | question_id
```

**I would like to get the top 3 users who asked the most questions for a specific keyword.**

To search a keyword inside a question, I use a [simple filter package](https://github.com/mehradsadeghi/laravel-filter-querystring). The code looks like that:

```php
Questions::with('user')
        ->filter()
        ->paginate();
```

To get the 3 users who asked the most questions without filtering anything, I wrote this code:

```php
UsersQuestions::with('user')
            ->select('mep_id')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderByDesc('count')
            ->limit(3)
            ->get();
```

But I can not figure out how to "mix" those two requests together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the result I want by doing two queries: first getting the right results and then by filtering the pivot table with the previous ids.

It is one way of doing it, but I'm not sure it is the best way.

```php
$questions = Questions::with('users')
                ->filter()
                ->pluck('id')
                ->toArray();

return QuestionsUsers::with('users')
            ->whereIn('question_id', $questions)
            ->select('user_id')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderByDesc('count')
            ->limit(3)
            ->get();
```